# Logic/Quantifiers and Proofs/counterexample

Tags: logic, quantifiers

How do I negate the following statement?

[image]

Also please help me with this exercise:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two questions in one are difficult to handle: just post two separate questions, please.  Also, the second question is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172279/11994 (for which I quite like my own answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/513115/11994).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question :**
$$\neg(c): (\exists x,y \in \Bbb R)(\exists z \in \Bbb Z)(\forall a \in \Bbb R) \quad a \geq \frac{x+y}{2} \vee a > z $$

**Second question:**

Let $x \in U$ where $U$ is the universal set indicated above. Then:

$$x \in (A\backslash B) \backslash C \iff x \in A \wedge x \notin B  \wedge x \notin C    $$ Let us call $(1)$  the right proposition of this equivalence.

$$x \in A\backslash(B \backslash C) \iff x \in A  \wedge x \notin B \backslash C$$   Let us call $(2)$  the right proposition of this equivalence.

if  $x \in A$  and  $x \notin B $ and $x \in C$  then $(2)$  holds   but not $(1)$

This allow us to construct a counter-example : let $A=C=\{1\}$  and $B=\{2\}$

Then  $(A\backslash B) \backslash C= \emptyset$ and  $A \backslash (B \backslash C)=\{1\}$

Comment: Thx, Mohamed!Just a small correction: (1) should be the left proposition.