# Prove associative of $(A \setminus B)\cup C = A \setminus (B \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to get some advice how to prove the associative property of the following:
$$(A \setminus B)\cup C = A \setminus  (B \cup C)$$
thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $(A\setminus B)\cup C=A\setminus(B\cup C)$? If so, you want `\setminus` instead of /.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct... Put $C=\Omega$ Do you mean symmetric difference by any chance?

Comment: If by $\;A/B\;$ you meant set difference, your formula is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $A=\varnothing$ and $C$ to be any non-empty set; then

$$(A\setminus B)\cup C=(\varnothing\setminus B)\cup C=\varnothing\cup C=C\;,$$

but

$$A\setminus(B\cup C)=\varnothing\setminus(B\cup C)=\varnothing\;.$$

In fact it’s always true that $(A\setminus B)\cup C\supseteq C$, while $\big(A\setminus(B\cup C)\big)\cap C=\varnothing$, so the two sets cannot be equal if $C$ is non-empty. On the other hand, if $C=\varnothing$ they are both just $A\setminus B$. Thus, they are equal if and only if $C=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is wrong as you presented. Take $A=\{1,2,3\}~~,B=\{1,2,4,5\}~~,C=\{3,7\}$. You'll see $(A-B)\cup C=C,~~~A-(B\cup C)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Through a proof very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/513115/11994 it is easy to simplify $$(A \setminus B)\cup C = A \setminus  (B \cup C)$$ to the equivalent $$C = \emptyset$$  So any non-empty $\;C\;$ is a counterexample.